# Why can't load data these fixtures in Symfony2 project?

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm, loading, fixtures

I've created a fixtures class inside my bundle's DataFixtures/ORM folder. The actual class looks like this:

```
use Doctrine\Common\DataFixtures\FixtureInterface,
    Company\ShoppingBundle\Entity\Category;

class CategoryFixtures implements FixtureInterface
{
    public function load($em)
    {
        $category1 = new Category()->setName("category1");
        $category2 = new Category()->setName("category2");
        $em->persist($category1);
        $em->persist($category2);
        $em->flush();
    }
}
```

I'm not using the AbstractFixture base class, since I don't need references. I've also tried specifying the fixtures path when running the doctrine:fixtures:load console command. I'm following the official docs [here](http://symfony.com/doc/current/bundles/DoctrineFixturesBundle/index.html).

Comment: What's the error you are getting that doesn't allow you to load the fixture? At an extreme guess its because you've done `$category1 = new Category()->setName("category1");` so unless the function `setName` returns a `Category` (most likely `$this` for your code to make sense) `$category1` will be getting assigned to null, you then try to persist null and flush it.

Comment: You're right about the incorrect assumption about what the setters return. I have since changed my code to call the setter after creating the object first. But this doesn't help me with the main problem. The error Im seeing is something like:

    [InvalidArgumentException]
    Could not find any fixtures to load in:

Followed by the list of folders its looking in (the list includes the folder where my fixtures class is :-)

Comment: In your code paste above you've not got a namespace on the fixture class, was that just an omission in your question? If not try to add it into `namespace Acme\WhateverBundle\DataFixtures\ORM;`

Comment: also, make sure the bundle is initialized in your `AppKernel.php`

Comment: Yes, I did have a namespace and missed it when I copy and pasted that code. And yes, the bundle is initialized in AppKernel too.

Weird thing today: I updated to Symfony 2.0.5 and then later on retried my load and it worked! Perhaps I had to clear out cache (I thought I had already done that). Also switched to using the AbstractFixture class and OrderedFixtureInterface. Wish I knew what "fixed" it :-)

Comment: AH, figured it out. My class did not have <?php at the top!

:-D

Comment: I resolved the same problem just now try this https://stackoverflow.com/a/47623728/1093932 :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Nothing wrong with the file naming, or my configuration: I simply forgot to put

```
<?php
```

at the top of my file :-D