# Symfony 3.4 and Fixtures Bundle issue with bundle version 3.0

Tags: php, symfony

I am trying to configure the bundle from : https://symfony.com/doc/master/bundles/DoctrineFixturesBundle/index.html

and when I try to run the command :

```
$ php bin/console doctrine:fixtures:load
```

getting error: 
In LoadDataFixturesDoctrineCommand.php line 95:
  Could not find any fixture services to load.

Comment: check here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47613979/symfony-3-4-0-could-not-find-any-fixture-services-to-load?rq=1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to update (app/config/services.yml)

```
services:
        resource: '../../src/DataFixtures/*'
```

https://symfony.com/doc/master/bundles/DoctrineFixturesBundle/index.html

Other problem is here in to the above tutorial

```
// src/DataFixtures/AppFixtures.php
namespace App\DataFixtures;
```

name space should be :

```
namespace DataFixtures;
```

Comment: services:
        resource: '../../src/DataFixtures/*' this part is missing in the documentation.